# Transaction reverts because of this line. Why?

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix

Inside my contract `Lipsum`, I have a function `doStuff(uint foo_)` which has the following line:

```
result = (a * (foo_ / 100) / b);
```

`result`, `a` and `b` are all `uint`.

If I call the function, it errors out in the mentioned line and returns the following:

```
transact to Lipsum.doStuff errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

This function does not deal with payments, it should not be payable, I'm not sending ETH values to it. I don't understand the reasoning behind this error. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `solidity 0.8.1` and Remix.

Comment: Hi! Would you mind putting the whole `doStuff` function into the question? Sometimes it's helpful to have the context.

Comment: Found the error. It was very basic *facepalm*. Posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this guys, I found the error. I was trying to get the `result` without having `b` with a valid value, so I was trying to do a division by 0.